# ODBC connection to Informix database from another Linux-based system

Tags: linux, odbc, informix

I want to connect to an Informix database using an ODBC connection from my web server.
Both Informix server and web server are implemented on different machines;
both system are using SuSE Linux.

I know very well how to create an ODBC connection on the same Informix server using unixODBC.

But I don't know how to create an ODBC connection from one Linux based machine to another machine where the Informix server is implemented.

If I use Windows 7 instead of Linux then Windows 7 provides ODBC connection template and there is also no problem in connectivity.

But how to do it with a client PC running Linux OS.

Please guide me.

Comment: Could it be a keyboard problem ?

Comment: how it could be a keyboard problem Please describe it. My web server is PHP based.

Comment: Anybody????? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect from one Linux machine to Informix database using ODBC then you have installed Informix ODBC client and one of ODBC managers. Such manager can be UnixODBC, Informix own manager or something else. On Linux those managers use `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` configuration files where you configure driver and connection.

Check how it is configured on Linux machine where it works: find those `.ini` files, check environmet variables (`INFORMIXDIR` and `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS`) and find ODBC manager (UnixODBC?). If you use UnixODBC then you can test connection with its `isql` utility.

Good info abour configuring Informix ODBC client on Linux can be found at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1108odbcdrivermanager/

Comment: Sir, I have two machine, one machine has informix database with linux OS, another has odbc driver + informix sdk with linux. I have problem in connection from 2nd machine to 1st machine's database using ODBC. Where should i configure my IP address of first machine in odbc configuration of 2nd machine. Please help me with full configuration details..... Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: In file pointed by `$INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` environment variable. See IBM documentation on configuring ODBC with various driver managers: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1108odbcdrivermanager/index.html